# Direction with putting one of my methods into a class

Tags: c#, entity-framework

It's difficult to explain what I want to do, I can't think of the right terms to Google. I am using Entity Framework 6 for a primarily data driven winform application. The primary construct is I have say 100 companies which are selected by a drop down, and an event triggered on the SelectedIndexChange which then pulls in the ID of the company I have changed to. Each and every company has a tab control with ten tabs each with different data in each (specific to the company). I need the sites (object?) below to persist across all these tabs but not on a selectedindexchange.

The code I am using (which works fine) looks a bit like this at the moment:

```
private MyModel context = new MyModel();
var sites = from s in context.Sites
            where s.Client_ID == value
            select s;
```

I need the sites var to persist across different forms and in different parts of my solution (for example different parts of my tab control. I also need to pass to it where required on a new company selectedindexchange the site_id as an integer. I'm sure this needs to go in a class of some sort but I'm struggling to scope out the logic and design.

Any direction would be gratefully appreciated.

I want the "var sites" to be created once and accessible across all the tabs for a single company UNTIL the selectedindexchange, at which point the var sites needs recreating by passing to it a new value in "where s.client_ID == value"

Comment: `I need the sites (object?) below to persist across all these tabs but not on a selectedindexchange.` do you mean have it be like by default (say instead of "select Option") and then go away completely once the drop down has changed? Or no, no matter what it is always there?

Comment: I think we need a bit more information.  (e.g. When is the data created?  How long do you need it to persist for?  What other objects needs to be able to access the data?)

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear - I've added an edit to the original post.